# getContext and withContext not working

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I've been trying to pass id to other component with context, but I get undefined, somewhere i'm making an error.
As I understand we should get context as props.
Any Ideas ?

```
import {compose,withContext} from 'recompose'


const ComponentOne = ({id}) => {
  console.log(id) // cizlory7iji600149711su9vj
...
}

const Context = withContext(
{id:React.PropTypes.string},
(props) => ({id:props.id})
)


export default compose(Context)(ComponentOne)
```

SecondComponent.js

```
import {compose,getContext} from 'recompose'

    const ComponentTwo = ({id}) => {
      console.log(id) // undefined
     ...
    }

    const GetContext = getContext(
      {id:React.PropTypes.string}
    )


    export default compose(GetContext)(ComponentTwo)
```

Comment: ComponentTwo is definitely a child of ComponentOne right? Maybe post a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks, it was that, don't know how I missed that crucial part...

Comment: Np, added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context only works from parents to children by passing props down, not siblings.

Make `ComponentTwo` a child of `ComponentOne`.